# Create PARTITION on MySql Table created via Code First implementation on EF6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-partitioning

I am using EF6 to create and populate a table with its primary key as a ServerTime (DateTime).

The table is very large, and in order to speed up access times as well as enjoy the benefit of having my table split into smaller partition files instead of one massive .ibd file when I perform an external query such as this:

```
SELECT
gbpusd.servertime,
gbpusd.orderbook
FROM
gbpusd
WHERE
gbpusd.servertime BETWEEN '2014-12-23 23:48:08.183000' AND '2015-03-23 23:48:08.183000'
```

I would like the table to be automatically partitioned by servertime during Code First creation.

I already know the raw MySql syntax for partitioning a table by range.

My current solution is to create and populate the database via EF6 Code first, and then manually execute the partitioning via raw MySQL query. Another solution is to use plain old ADO.NET directly after Code First creation, but I would have rather have everything streamlined inside EF6 code.

What I need to know is how I can accomplish the same thing via Code First implementation (assuming it is even possible)

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it about only speed up ? Where you need to populate this data? Assuming you have service layer or manager to use this entity.You can always use use your repository to perform over your  entity using lembda expression.

example

```
using (var dataBaseContext= new your_DbContext())
{
  var repoServer = new Repository<gbpusd>(dataBaseContext);  
  var searchedGbpusd =repoServer.SearchFor(i=> i.servertime <= date && i.servertime >= date).select;
///you can specify date what ever you like
///use this searched Data where ever you want to use.
}
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks
Fahad

Comment: The database is several gigabytes in size, spanning several months. In my first test comparing a partitioned to non-partitioned table with raw queries, I found that performance was drastically improved with a partition. Furthermore, it allows me to archive older partitions as smaller separate files on other disks, verses having a huge gigabyte sized table that must stay on the active hard drive. I plan to use a repository pattern, but would still like to have my table partitioned as well. There is the convenience of having my data split between smaller partition files as well as speed.

Comment: Hi again, You can just create your entity using EF6 code first practice. Using search via repository practice search the data and fill in that table. Like I suggested , use searched data and then fill the data and run this activity as frequently as you need. Like can do when users are not on peak.

Comment: No. This does not answer the original question. Currently, my .idb database file is over 100 gigabytes in size. All records sit on this one file on my active hard drive. Some records are from over a year ago, and are not accessed as often, and hence could be separated out and moved to a secondary drive. By partitioning my table by range, I can split this massive .idb file into smaller ones, each one containing the records for a specific datetime range. In this way, I could move the least accessed records to a sub-drive,freeing up necessary hard drive space. I need partitioning to do this.

Comment: @guerrillacodester Hi, I know that a long time has passed, but have you found then any solution? I have similar problem today and still no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create your entity using EF6 code first practice. Using search via repository practice search the data and fill in that table. Like I suggested , use searched data and then fill the data and run this activity as frequently as you need. Like can do when users are not on peak. –  Shaikh Muhammad Fahad 1

Comment: No. This does not answer the original question. Currently, my .idb database file is over 100 gigabytes in size. All records sit on this one file on my active hard drive. Some records are from over a year ago, and are not accessed as often, and hence could be separated out and moved to a secondary drive. By partitioning my table by range, I can split this massive .idb file into smaller ones, each one containing the records for a specific datetime range. In this way, I could move the least accessed records to a sub-drive,freeing up necessary hard drive space. I need partitioning to do this.